# What is the proper syntax to add a hash key/value pair to an array in PHP?

Tags: php, hashmap

I want to add a Hash key/value pair to an empty array.

Here is how I am trying to do it, however I am getting an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW
```

Here is my code:

```
$key = (string)$degree->f[0];
$value = (string)$degree->f[1];        
$SDP_ID2CohortMap[] = ( $key => $value );
```

Comment: and you could not find that in the PHP Manual?

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$SDP_ID2CohortMap = array( $key => $value );
$SDP_ID2CohortMap[$key] = $value;
```

But not both at the same time.

Comment: Answered in under 2 min. Tested and verified in under 5min. This site and its members are amazing!

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to create a union of two arrays, which can be done with the [PHP array union operator<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/language.operators.array.php):

```
$key   = (string)$degree->f[0];
$value = (string)$degree->f[1];        

$SDP_ID2CohortMap += array($key => $value);
                  ^^^^^^^^
```

Probably this information is helpful for you.